# Google Maps link validation using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, google-maps, url

I just only want to check if that link is Google Maps link

**For example :**

```
var urls =[
    /// correct urls
    "https://www.google.com/maps",
    "https://www.google.fr/maps",
    "https://google.fr/maps",
    "http://google.fr/maps",
    "https://www.google.de/maps",
    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
    "https://www.google.de/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4&layer=t&lci=com.panoramio.all,com.google.webcams,weather",
    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.370157,0.615234&spn=45.047033,93.076172&t=m&z=4&layer=t",

    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
    "https://www.google.de/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4&layer=t&lci=com.panoramio.all,com.google.webcams,weather",
    "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.370157,0.615234&spn=45.047033,93.076172&t=m&z=4&layer=t",

    /// error urls
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://zzz.google.com/maps",
    "https://www.google.com/+",
    "httpsxyz://www.google.com/maps",
    "http://www.anotherdomain.com/+"
    ];
```

I'm so bad about Regex and tried to use JavaScript Regex Generator but its still hard for me.

I got only ..

```
Reg = /^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/|www\.google$/;
```

and its fail ! :(

But I made a live test for you all : http://jsbin.com/onuyux/1/edit?javascript,live

---

**Edited : 2**

After I got help from `@joel harkes` & `@dan1111` so i got regex

```
/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\b/
```

This is regex for only `google.{TLD}/maps` so what about maps.google.{TLD} ?

**I just want to validate Google Maps URLs** and urls from this way *(look at the picture)*

[image]

**If possible** I want to validate if address or long-lat is set (using `li` or `q` parameter check ?) (not only "maps.google.com" for example..)

**Updated list + code :**

```
/// correct urls
"https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
"https://www.google.de/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4",
"https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4&layer=t&lci=com.panoramio.all,com.google.webcams,weather",
"https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.370157,0.615234&spn=45.047033,93.076172&t=m&z=4&layer=t",
"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York,+NY,+USA&hl=no&sll=19.808054,-63.720703&sspn=54.337928,93.076172&oq=n&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10",
"https://www.google.com/maps?q=New+York,+New+York,+USA&hl=no&ll=40.683762,-73.925629&spn=0.708146,1.454315&sll=41.47566,-72.026367&sspn=11.190693,23.269043&oq=new&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10",

/// error urls
"https://www.google.com/",
"https://zzz.google.com/maps",
"https://www.google.com/+",
"httpsxyz://www.google.com/maps",
"http://www.anotherdomain.com/+",
"http://maps.google.com/",
"http://google.com/maps",
"http://google.de/maps",
"?q=New+York,+New+York,+USA&hl=no&ll=40.683762,-73.925629&spn=0.708146,1.454315&sll=41.47566,-72.026367&sspn=11.190693,23.269043&oq=new&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10",
"&sll=41.47566,-72.026367&sspn=11.190693,23.269043&oq=new&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10"
```

**Live test :** http://jsbin.com/onuyux/25/edit?javascript,live

Comment: +1 for the live test.  Very helpful.

Comment: Per your comment "This is regex for only google.{TLD}/maps so what about maps.google.{TLD}", javascript doesn't support look-behinds, so you would need to create another regular expression specifically for "maps.google.com", etc that doesn't have to match '/maps' at the end.  After you create the second expression, check with both of them, if one matches, then it is good, if none match then it isn't. ^^

Comment: but just one error now : http://jsbin.com/onuyux/25/edit?javascript,live @Jon

Comment: Oh just maps.google.com get error

Comment: According to that last live example, it's because the regex doesn't allow for `(www\.|maps\.)` which would fix it for that one line, but fail if the url is "maps.google.com/?q=" (which is valid if everything after the question mark matches your other conditions.).  If you have 'maps.google', you don't need '/maps' at the end, which is where back-referencing would come in to play in a language other than JS.  If you have '(www\.|maps\.)' and then make '/maps' conditional as well, it would be too flexible - thus why you need to compare against two regex in order to match all possible urls.

Comment: @jon http://jsbin.com/onuyux/31/edit?javascript,live Can you look at this ? But I want to check if domainname if `google` also

Comment: I would have kept the original regex you had, but then add a new one that had it as `(maps\.)?` instead of 'www.', and on that one make `\/(maps)?` after the {TLD}

Comment: Don't forget about domains like `google.co.uk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing **dan1111**'s answer here's a pattern that will match the specified domains and check if the ll GET variable is set:

```
Reg = /^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&+])+($|&)/;
```

I could not test it (jsbin is down) but it should match any url that contains at least one of ll or q parameters.

**EDIT**:

I added the maps. subdomain and fixed a small typo. After `q=` the `+` should be outside of the character class, to let it repeat: `q=[^&]+` instead of `q=[^&+]`.
That being said, here's your regex:

```
Reg = /^https?\:\/\/(www\.|maps\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&]+)+($|&)/;
```

**EDIT2**:

To accept the google.co.uk style domains use the following regex.

```
Reg = /^https?\:\/\/(www\.|maps\.)?google(\.[a-z]+){1,2}\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&]+)+($|&)/;
```

Hope it will cover all the urls now.

Comment: error : `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York,+NY,+USA&hl=no&sll=19.808054,-63.720703&sspn=54.337928,93.076172&oq=n&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10` (for example) `q` parameter ?

Comment: + added link with `q` parameter in my list now :D http://jsbin.com/onuyux/17/edit?javascript,live

Comment: @l2aelba So to clarify, you want to check that both ll and q is set, or either one of those?

Comment: all working links :D some user add by name or same user pointing to position like long-lat :D Your regex is work but can you add `q` parameter also ?

Comment: i have to go now , coming to look your regex asap. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: done with this : `/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*|(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&+])+($|&)/`it's right regex ? I just add `|` before `ll`

Comment: @l2aelba No it's not. The regex you made will match to both `https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*|(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9‌​]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+` OR `(ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9‌​]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&+])+($|&)`. I updated my answer to make it better :)

Comment: Can you input this link in your answer ? http://jsbin.com/onuyux/37/?javascript,live

Comment: Yeah ! After @Qtax comment domain like google.co.uk get error http://jsbin.com/onuyux/38/edit

Answer (score 2):

```
(https|http)://(www\.|)google\.[a-z]+/maps
```

-> with slashes:`/(https|http):\/\/(www\.|)google\.[a-z]+\/maps/`

that regex selects only the good urls not the bad, but doesnt check enny \GET variables

you can test at: http://regexpal.com/ or here http://jsbin.com/onuyux/4

you can add ^ in front to test if it is start of string

Comment: Thanks so much :D , Your regex is so simple :D Work ! http://jsbin.com/onuyux/5/edit?javascript,live

Comment: you can use `(https|http)://(www\.|)google\.[a-z]+/maps($|\?)` which will check if its end of string or followed by a ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple regex that will work on your test data:

```
Reg = /^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.(com|fr|de)\/maps\b/;
```

However, you should probably take a step back and think more about what you are trying to do.  You have two separate problems here:

- Verify that something is a valid URL (I assume you need to do this because one of your examples is an invalid URL).
- Verify that a URL is a Google Maps URL.

If you want a robust solution, I suggest doing it in a two-step process. First determine that the URL is valid, then see if it is a Google Maps URL.

The first part is quite complex in itself, but many others have tackled it before.  If you search for "Javascript URL Validation" you will see many questions and many proposed answers.  I suggest [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044420/1919238) as a place to start, but I don't have any personal experience of doing this in Javascript.

For the second part, you have to determine exactly what a Google Maps URL can look like.  You have given some examples above, but they are clearly a subset of the possibilities.  How exhaustive do you want to be?  And do you need to verify that the parameters are valid, as well?  This could be a huge task.

Comment: sorry , my fail. Not only `(com|fr|de)` and only `maps` not `mapsz` (for example)

Comment: I got now : `/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\b/` thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
Reg = /^https?\:\/\/((www|maps)\.)?google\.[a-z]+\/maps\/?\?([^&]+&)*(s?ll=-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+|q=[^&+])+($|&)/;
```

Can test it in http://jsbin.com/onuyux/36

Answer (score -1):

you can use this regex to validate both domains "maps.apps.goo.gl" or "www.google.com"

```
/^(https?\:\/\/)?(maps\.app\.goo\.gl|www\.google\.com)\/.+$/
```

you can test this on : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please considering updating your answer to include the test data provided by [l2aelba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622813/l2aelba). This regex needs significant changes to be applicable to the question.